# Replacing EXISTS JOIN with JOIN

Tags: axapta, x++

I am having trouble with the AX2012 class (default AX2012 class and code, no modifications have been made on it): `CustVendTransDetails` in the method `calcCashDiscounts`

The following query is giving me the error `The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.`:

```
if (TaxParameters::canApplyCashDiscOnInvoice_ES())
{
    insert_recordset tmpValue
        (CustVendTransRefRecId, AmountMST)
        select CustVendTransRefRecId
        from _custVendAccountStatementIntTmpProcessing

        exists join custVendTransLoc
        where
            custVendTransLoc.RecId == _custVendAccountStatementIntTmpProcessing.CustVendTransRefRecId

        exists join firstOnly subledgerVoucherGeneralJournalEntry
        where
            subledgerVoucherGeneralJournalEntry.Voucher == custVendTransLoc.Voucher &&
            subledgerVoucherGeneralJournalEntry.AccountingDate == custVendTransLoc.TransDate

        exists join generalJournalEntry
        where
            generalJournalEntry.RecId == subledgerVoucherGeneralJournalEntry.GeneralJournalEntry &&
            generalJournalEntry.Ledger == Ledger::current()

        join AccountingCurrencyAmount from generalJournalAccountEntry
        where
            generalJournalAccountEntry.GeneralJournalEntry == generalJournalEntry.RecId &&
            (generalJournalAccountEntry.PostingType == LedgerPostingType::CustCashDisc ||
            generalJournalAccountEntry.PostingType == LedgerPostingType::VendCashDisc);

    update_recordSet _custVendAccountStatementIntTmpProcessing setting
        UtilizedCashDisc = tmpValue.AmountMST,
        PossibleCashDisc = tmpValue.AmountMST
        join tmpValue
        where
            tmpValue.CustVendTransRefRecId == _custVendAccountStatementIntTmpProcessing.CustVendTransRefRecId;
}
```

I understand why, but I am not sure how to solve this problem. Will it be a problem to replace the `exist join` with a normal `join`?

Replacing the `exist join` with `join`, does solve my problem, but I am not sure what difference it will make to the data? Because it is only is selecting 1 field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to switch the order of joins:

```
insert_recordset tmpValue (CustVendTransRefRecId, AmountMST)
    select CustVendTransRefRecId
    from _custVendAccountStatementIntTmpProcessing

    join AccountingCurrencyAmount from generalJournalAccountEntry // Moved up
    where generalJournalAccountEntry.PostingType == LedgerPostingType::CustCashDisc ||
          generalJournalAccountEntry.PostingType == LedgerPostingType::VendCashDisc

    exists join custVendTransLoc
    where
        custVendTransLoc.RecId == _custVendAccountStatementIntTmpProcessing.CustVendTransRefRecId

    exists join firstOnly subledgerVoucherGeneralJournalEntry
    where
        subledgerVoucherGeneralJournalEntry.Voucher == custVendTransLoc.Voucher &&
        subledgerVoucherGeneralJournalEntry.AccountingDate == custVendTransLoc.TransDate

    exists join generalJournalEntry
    where
        generalJournalEntry.RecId == subledgerVoucherGeneralJournalEntry.GeneralJournalEntry && &&
        generalJournalEntry.RecId == generalJournalAccountEntry.GeneralJournalEntry && // Moved from join
        generalJournalEntry.Ledger == Ledger::current();
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the exist join with join will not fix your issue. Exist is a way to join to essentially inner join to a table without returning any fields.

The query should return CustVendTransRefRecId from _custVendAccountStatementIntTmpProcessing and AccountingCurrencyAmount from generalJournalAccountEntry which is exactly what the insert is expecting.

I expect the query isn't actually returning anything. Check the criteria it is using and check the data.